# Combine a grid of images into a single figure WITHOUT subfigures and labels, captions, etc

Tags: subfloats, subcaption

**MWE:**

```
\begin{figure*}
\subfloat[\label{fig:test1}]
  {\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{one}}\hfill
\subfloat[unwanted caption\label{fig:test2}]
  {\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{two}}\hfill
\caption{Something something, etc. a desired overall caption}
\end{figure*}
```

This will produce a figure with an overall (desired) caption, and two subfigures, oriented left and right. The left figure will have a "caption" which just says

```
(a)
```

and the right figure will have caption

```
(b) unwanted caption
```

**1. How do I remove these captions entirely so that the two images appear to be simply part of one overall figure?**

**2. How can I generalize this simply to allow for a 2x2 grid of 4 images, combined with just one overall caption and no individual (a),(b), (c), (d) or captions?**

Also, generically, the `subcaption` package doesn't work for me, so I really hope you can suggest a way to accomplish this without that...

Comment: If you don't need subfloats, don't use subfloats. `\includegraphics{a}\hfill\includegraphics{b}\par\includegraphics{c}\hfill\includegraphics{d}`. Instead of `\par` you can add a blank line.

Comment: Please always provide a *complete* example which can be copy-paste-compiled to reproduce the issue. In this case, just don't use `\subfloat` or `subfigure` or `sub` anything. Just use `\includegraphics` or, if necessary, `minipage`s or similar.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. See [below](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/307478/combine-a-grid-of-images-into-a-single-figure-without-subfigures-and-labels-cap/307484?noredirect=1#comment750830_307484).

Answer (score 5):

The comments above basically gave me the answer, and here it is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
 \includegraphics[width=.48\linewidth]{example-image-a} \hfill
 \includegraphics[width=.48\linewidth]{example-image-b} \\
 \vspace{5mm}

 \includegraphics[width=.48\linewidth]{example-image-c}\hfill
 \includegraphics[width=.48\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{Something something, overall}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Asking a question, getting help and then taking credit for it is somewhat discourteous. It would be better - and more usual - to ask one of the commenters to write up an answer you could accept so that they get the credit. In this case, you should definitely ask  Torbjørn T. to write the answer. Also, answers - like questions - should typically include a complete example.

Comment: That's fair. I don't mean to take credit for the solution. If Torbjørn T. wants to take the time to write a complete example solution, like you say, I will gladly "accept it as the genuine solution" with a checkmark. I wrote this answer for other readers who come here from google in the future and just want to copy paste this solution.

Comment: Nevermind. As @cfr says it is customary to ask commenters to make answers, but no need for any more fuzz here. Part of the reason I only commented in the first place was that I was sure there was a duplicate somewhere, but I wasn't able to find it, and then I forgot about it. If you feel bad, find an answer of mine and give it an upvote :). I also edited your code a bit.