# How to put 12 figures in 3 columns?

Tags: floats

Here is my effort: I want to put 12 figures in three columns and four rows. Can anyone demonstrate that how should do this correctly? Following gives 1 column with 4 figures. Need to generate another two columns.

```
\begin{figure} 
\minipage{0.50\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{20} 
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{30}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{37}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{40}
\endminipage\hfill
\end{figure}
```

After reading comments this got following

```
\begin{figure} 
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{m4crack30}\hfill%
\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{m4crack30}\hfill%
\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{m4crack30}\hfill%
\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{m4crack30}\hfill%
\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{m4crack30}\hfill%
\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{m4crack30}\hfill%
\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{m4crack30}\hfill%
\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{m4crack30}\hfill%

\end{figure}
```

issue is to not getting in full size by removing minipage!

The question is still on pending! No helpful answer yet.

Comment: Well, if your `minipage` is only `0.50\textwidth`, each image will have to have a width less than `0.125\textwidth` to get 4 of them across the `minipage`.

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes How can I keep the full scale of picture that I have? Let see, how should I change above lines to get three more column. can you change that?

Comment: You can do essentially the same as in [Combine a grid of images into a single figure WITHOUT subfigures and labels, captions, etc](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/307484), just reduce the width of the figures to `0.3\textwidth`.

Comment: Bring an example! I did not get any answer so far that can help.

Comment: In your revised example, each figure is `.25\textwidth` wide, and you have no line breaks ( \\ ) between them.  Thus you are trying to place 8x(`.25\textwidth`) = `2\textwidth` worth of images in a `1\textwidth` space.  If you want 4 images per line, I suggest changing `\25\textwidth` to `,24\textwidth` to leave a little gap, and then, after the 4th image, change the `\hfill` to \\ .

Comment: Another thing: If you don't want to scale your images, then use just `\includegraphics{filename}`. However, if your images are wider than a quarter of the width of the text, you obviously cannot fit four images in one line. You seem to want to fit four too large images in one line, and that just can't workI may misunderstand you completely though, I find it difficult to understand exactly where the confusion lies.

Answer (score 3):

The OP requests an example, so here is one. I set each figure to `.32\textwidth`, so that 3 of them not quite fill up a line.  I place `\hfill` between them to give even separation.  I use `\\` between lines.

All of this is within a `minipage` of `.5\textwidth`, though that doesn't necessarily make sense by itself inside a `figure` environment, unless you were going to add a second `minipage` to the same figure, so I added one as an example.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure} 
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth,height=1cm]{30}\hfill%
\includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth,height=1cm]{37}\hfill%
\includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth,height=1cm]{40}\\
\includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth,height=1cm]{20}\hfill%
\includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth,height=1cm]{37}\hfill%
\includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth,height=1cm]{40}\\
\includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth,height=1cm]{20}\hfill%
\includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth,height=1cm]{37}\hfill%
\includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth,height=1cm]{40}\\
\includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth,height=1cm]{20}\hfill%
\includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth,height=1cm]{37}\hfill%
\includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth,height=1cm]{40}
\end{minipage}%
\fboxsep=-\fboxrule%
\fbox{\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
Here is a 2nd minipage in the same figure.
\end{minipage}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As Torbjorn suggests, if you want a full-width figure array, get rid of the `minipage`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth,height=2cm]{30}\hfill%
\includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth,height=2cm]{37}\hfill%
\includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth,height=2cm]{40}\\
\includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth,height=2cm]{20}\hfill%
\includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth,height=2cm]{37}\hfill%
\includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth,height=2cm]{40}\\
\includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth,height=2cm]{20}\hfill%
\includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth,height=2cm]{37}\hfill%
\includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth,height=2cm]{40}\\
\includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth,height=2cm]{20}\hfill%
\includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth,height=2cm]{37}\hfill%
\includegraphics[width=.32\textwidth,height=2cm]{40}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: that is good! question: if I want to keep the original height of my picture and not forcing that to 1cm..what should I do?

Comment: @Mohammad If you add only `width=0.32\textwidth` the aspect ratio is preserved.

Comment: @Mohammad Do as Torbjorn suggests, omit the `height=` specification.  I just added a `height=` constraint to keep the demonstration version from producing very tall figures.

Comment: I am almost there! the issue now is that I have above figure (black boxes) in a small portion of full page (letter size). How can I magnify that in the same size of full page (of course its size will meet margins)

Comment: @Mohammad If you want them to fill the whole width of the text block, remove the `minipage` environment.

Comment: @Mohammad Your comment is not fully clear to me.  This is why the site policy is to request that the questioner post a minimum working example (MWE) as part of their question, fully compileable code that demonstrates the problem.  Several things to remember: in my example, images are black boxes because I have specified `[demo]` in the `\usepackage{graphicx}` specification.  Remove `[demo]` to get actual figures.

Comment: @Mohammad Based on Torbjorn's comment, I added a revision to my answer.  Perhaps that helps your need.

Comment: I have removed the /minipage however it does not change yet! @StevenB.Segletes mt MWE was posted in original question.

Comment: @Mohammad But haven't you changed any of your code since posting that? Are you using anything like what Steven has in his answer (bottom half)? And what doesn't change?

Comment: I did implement changes in original problem statement. Please see.

Answer (score 2):

With `tcbraster` from `tcolorbox` it's very easy to organize graphics (boxes) into an array form. Just decide number of columns and `tcbraster` will decide everything else.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=3, enhanced, blankest]
\tcbincludegraphics{example-image}
\tcbincludegraphics{example-image}
\tcbincludegraphics{example-image}
\tcbincludegraphics{example-image}
\tcbincludegraphics{example-image}
\tcbincludegraphics{example-image}
\tcbincludegraphics{example-image}
\tcbincludegraphics{example-image}
\tcbincludegraphics{example-image}
\tcbincludegraphics{example-image}
\tcbincludegraphics{example-image}
\tcbincludegraphics{example-image}
\end{tcbraster}
\caption{This is my figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It does not compile! can I change anything?

Comment: @Mohammad   And what's the error shown?

Comment: l.10....ter}[raster columns4, enhanced, blanket]

Comment: package pgfkeys error

Comment: I'd suggest to update tcolorbox.

Comment: how should i do that

Comment: What did you write: "raster columns4" or "raster columns=4"?

Comment: just typo ..raster columns=4 is in log file (error)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40343/discussion-between-ignasi-and-mohammad).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that uses three side-by-side `minipage` environments, each with width `0.33\textwidth`.

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % omit 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure} 
\hfill a \hfill\hfill b \hfill\hfill c \hfill{} % fake header row    
\medskip

\begin{minipage}{0.33\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{a1} 
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{a2}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{a3}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{a4}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.33\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{b1} 
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{b2}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{b3}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{b4}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.33\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{c1} 
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{c2}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{c3}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{c4}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If placing the 12 pictures in 3 columns/4 rows results in making them too small to be useful and/or appealing, you may want to try placing them in 2 columns/6 rows instead (see below). This may work out quite well if the pictures are in landscape mode. If, however, they are in portrait mode, you may find it necessary to place the images across two pages, i.e., two `figure` environments each with 2 columns/3 rows of pictures.

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % omit 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set page parameters
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[p]
\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{a1}
\hfill 
\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{a2}

\bigskip
\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{a3}
\hfill 
\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{a4}

\bigskip\bigskip
\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{b1}
\hfill 
\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{b2}

\bigskip
\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{b3}
\hfill 
\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{b4}

\bigskip\bigskip
\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{c1}
\hfill 
\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{c2}

\bigskip
\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{c3}\hfill 
\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{c4}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

---

*Second addendum*: Here's a possible solution for square-sized images: The code places 6 images per page, in 2 columns/3 rows per page.

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % omit 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set page parameters

\newlength\mylength
\setlength\mylength{0.425\textwidth} % figure dimensions

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[p] % first figure
\includegraphics[width=\mylength,height=\mylength]{a1}
\hfill 
\includegraphics[width=\mylength,height=\mylength]{a2}

\bigskip\bigskip
\includegraphics[width=\mylength,height=\mylength]{a3}
\hfill 
\includegraphics[width=\mylength,height=\mylength]{a4}

\bigskip\bigskip
\includegraphics[width=\mylength,height=\mylength]{a5}
\hfill 
\includegraphics[width=\mylength,height=\mylength]{a6}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[p] % second figure
\includegraphics[width=\mylength,height=\mylength]{b1}
\hfill 
\includegraphics[width=\mylength,height=\mylength]{b2}

\bigskip\bigskip
\includegraphics[width=\mylength,height=\mylength]{b3}
\hfill 
\includegraphics[width=\mylength,height=\mylength]{b4}

\bigskip\bigskip
\includegraphics[width=\mylength,height=\mylength]{b5}
\hfill 
\includegraphics[width=\mylength,height=\mylength]{b6}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @ Mico, this is good but the issue (as same as previous answer) the figures became smaller like as figures scaled down! I want to keep aspect ratio

Comment: I think if I want to keep the actual size of my pictures, then I have to do something else in LaTex - the paradox is if I remove the optional from above code then I can not have this columns for figures and if keep them I can not keep actual size of pictures

Comment: @Mohammad - Are your pictures square, portrait-format, or landscape-format? How big is your paper size (US letter, A4, something else?), and how wide are the margins?

Comment: @ Mico they are square, jpg format. there are four pictures I want to put in letter size picture. It seems that I have to crop my figures manually if I want to use above code you suggested

Comment: @ Mico assume that each size of photo is 1/4 of latter size. there should be a way that i can fit them in latex

Comment: @Mohammad - Did you mean to write "letter size" instead of "latter size"?

Comment: A4 and latter size

Comment: @Mohammad - Please advise what "latter size" means.