# Arrange / align external images in grid with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I'm trying to use TikZ to combine four raster images into a single figure and annotate the images. If you feel like asking why, see *.

My first problem is arranging / aligning the images in a grid.

The code below sort of gets the job done, but the order in which the images appear is not what I would expect. I would expect

```
[a][b]
[c][d]
```

but I get
[image: Screenshot of images a, b, c, d arranged in grid]

```
% remember usepackage{tikz}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=north west ,inner sep=0] (frame1) at (0,0)        
    {\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{a.png}};

    \node[anchor=north east,inner sep=0] (frame2) at (0,0)        
    {\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{b.png}};

    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (frame3) at (0,0)        
    {\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{c.png}};

    \node[anchor=south east,inner sep=0] (frame4) at (0,0)        
    {\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{d.png}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{My caption}
\end{figure}
```

How would you arrange these four images in a 2x2 grid, preferably in a predictable order?

*Scientific journals often expect a single pdf or tiff file for each figure, combining images with the subfigure environment or similar is not an option since they do not support exporting the figure you created to a seperate pdf file, but TikZ does. And I need this single pdf file to submit as the final figure. Combining and annotating in an external graphics editor like Inkscape introduces the problem of fonts, font sizes etc. Much nicer to have LaTeX do the annotation to get the right font and size.

Comment: When setting `achor=north west` it means that the image (a) will have its upper left corner at position 0.0. For (b) the same would be its top right corner. So you see that if you just change the anchors, it will work. But for a bigger grid, your solution wouldn't work. you could use a `tabular`. why can't you use a `subfigure` or `subfig`?

Comment: @RunarTrollet On why I can't use subfigure, my original post contained an "If you feel like asking why, see *."

Comment: It doesnt say why, just that it "is not at option"

Comment: Right, my bad. I assumed that it was clear I meant to externalize the tikz picture so i had this single pdf file to submit as a figure, but I didn't write it, so how could it be clear? Also I assumed it was clear that there is no way to have figure/subfigure generate a single pdf representing that figure. I'll update my *-section.

Comment: Also, you are right about the anchor point. I thought "anchor=north west" meant place the node north west of the coordinate.  If that was the case "anchor=north west" would place the image above (0,0) to the left, which is where I wanted image A to go (top left).

Comment: Allthough Tikz is of course a good way to accomplish this, the same could be accomplished with a `tabular` or subfigure.

Comment: Not if I want to generate a standalone pdf of the figure afterwards, which I can then submit to the journal. In that case I would have to put that subfigure code into a seperate tex document and compile with the standalone documentclass or similar. With TikZ externalize feature I can have the figure in my document (to fiddle with it) and have tikz generate an external pdf version of it. Also if I want the (A) labels etc. to appear on top of the images (typographical area comes at a premium cost in journal articles) I couldn't do that with subfigure.

Comment: Related?: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311628/how-to-put-12-figures-in-3-columns/311665#311665

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
 image/.style = {text width=0.45\textwidth, 
                 inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt},
node distance = 1mm and 1mm
                        ] 
\node [image] (frame1)
    {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}};
\node [image,right=of frame1] (frame2) 
    {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}};
\node[image,below=of frame1] (frame3)
    {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}};
\node[image,right=of frame3] (frame4)
    {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{My caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, I add TikZ library `positioning, by which I control distance between picture. Also I use it in placement of nodes with images.

Comment: Better solution. This seems to be extendable to n x m by simply continuing "right=of frame1", "right=of frame2" etc. There will always be manual labor involved in something like this, after all I want to control which image goes where.

Comment: I have to confess I drew up my image A, B, C, and D in inkscape. This is my first use of TikZ and pgf, so I didn't know about "example-image-a" etc.

Comment: @JonasCamillusJeppesen, nodes you can concatenated in chains. This has sense, if you have more that two images in row or column. In this case you need to position "manually" only the first node in each chain. `example-image` are from packages `graphcx`, unfortunately only A, B C and without letter name.

Answer (score 4):

I think `tcbraster` provides an easier solution. You fix the columns number and add as many figures you need with `tcbincludegraphics`. The appearance order is the same you introduces into the `tcbraster`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=2, enhanced, blankest]
    \tcbincludegraphics{example-image-a}
    \tcbincludegraphics{example-image-b}
    \tcbincludegraphics{example-image-c}
    \tcbincludegraphics{example-image}
    \end{tcbraster}
    \caption{My caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1, very useful answer! I've added [complements](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/500589/73317) based on this technique for people who want to produce an overview of the various pages of a document (each image put in the `tcbraster` is a page extracted from a “master” document). This can be useful if you have code that produces several pages and you want to show them in an answer, but don't want to upload several screenshots, because it often occupies a lot of visual space in the answer—plus, uploading several screenshots takes non-negligible time.

Answer (score 1):

A variant of [Ignasi's nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/324550/73317) that can be useful if the images you want to arrange are pages from a given PDF file (let's call it `foobar.pdf`).

## Preparing the `tcbraster` box

In this example, we prepare a `tcbraster` box containing thumbnails for pages 1 to 11 of `foobar.pdf`, arranged in four columns using English reading order (i.e., left to right, then top to bottom).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{raster, skins}

% No page numbers. This is useful in case you want to use pdfcrop
% afterwards to extract just the tcbraster box (see below).
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=4, enhanced, blankest]
  \foreach \page in {1,...,11} {%
    \tcbincludegraphics[graphics options={page=\page}]{foobar}%
  }
\end{tcbraster}
\end{document}
```

[image: Thumbnails]

Note: the background image sequence in the original file is really A, B, C, A, B, C, A, B, A, B, A (see below for the source); this is not a bug.

The `graphics options` option of `\tcbincludegraphics` was used to pass option `pages=...` to the underlying `\includegraphics` command, in order to select each page separately.

In case you want to reproduce exactly this screenshot, the `foobar.tex` file used to produce `foobar.pdf` can be found in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/500576/73317).

## Automatic cropping of the result

The previous code wrote the `tcbraster` box to a PDF file in letter format (this is the default, since we didn't pass any option such as `a4paper` to `\documentclass`, nor did we use a package such as `geometry`). In case you have the `pdfcrop` tool, you can automatically produce a PDF file whose format is a tight fit around the `tcbraster` box (we add a margin of `3bp`, where a `bp` is 1/72 of an inch):

```sh
pdfcrop --margins 3 foobar.pdf
```

This writes the result to `foobar-crop.pdf` (one could have passed an additional argument to `pdfcrop` in order to specify the name of the output file).

Finally, one can create a PNG file at resolution, e.g., 384 dpi, from this `foobar-crop.pdf`:

```sh
pdftoppm -png -r 384 foobar-crop.pdf >foobar-crop.png
```

Don't forget the redirection (the `>foobar-crop.png` part)!